# how to trigger function on dropdownlist item selection

Tags: java, android, filter, drop-down-menu

i am new to android studio and I am stuck in a scenario, I have a recylerview where all data visible and i want to show data only base on selected city from downlist. any suggestion that how i can achieve that. also guide me that how can I use spinner for filtering

Answer (score 1):

In Spinner to call a method when a item is selected you can use setOnItemSelectedListener()

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                // code which needs to be executed when item selected
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

For more details you can visit : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener